# Expression must have class type. - Vector of class objects

Tags: c++, stdvector

Can someone point me in the right direction of where to look please? I'm getting the above error.

std::vector of class States declared in game engine class.

```
class GameEngine
{....
 private:
 std::vector<State> *m_states;
}
```

Within the Constructor:

```
m_states = new std::vector<State>;
```

Add state function

```
void GameEngine::AddState(State *state, bool change)
{
   m_states.push_back (state);
   .....
}
```

"Error  3   error C2228: left of '.push_back' must have class/struct/union"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dont use new `std::vector<State> *m_states;`  -> `std::vector<State> m_states;`  (your original error is because you forgot to dereference : `m_states->push_back (state);` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared m_states as a pointer ...

```
...
private:
 std::vector<State> *m_states;
...
```

so, you have to use it as a pointer.

Write `m_states->push_back` instead of `m_states.push_back`.

On the other hand I can see you have another error in your code:

your `GameEngine::AddState(State *state, bool change)` function receives a `State *` as the first argument, but your `m_states` member is a vector of `State` objects not pointers. You have to change your declaration to:

```
std::vector<States *> *m_states;
```

**Advice:** Try to avoid using pointers (*) in C++, use **[smart_pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279674.aspx)** instead.

Comment: This "fix" might be incorrect, it depends on how the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating a pointer, you need to dereference it before pushing back anything into the vector.

```
(*m_states).push_back (state);
```

Or simply:

```
m_states->push_back (state);
```